# Why does this Concourse pipeline not run all the way through?

Tags: pipeline, concourse

We have a pipeline with 3 stages:

1. Building a lib
2. Building an application that depends on the lib.
3. Packinging the app into a distro (the app inlines the lib, so the distro is only directly dependent on the app).

If we make a commit to the lib, it should be built, then trigger the app to be built with the new lib, and finally, the distro to be repackaged.  The job-plan for the distro includes this:

```
  - name: build-distro
    serial_groups: [grp]
    plan:
      - get: app
        passed: [build-app]
        trigger: true
      - get: distro
        trigger: true
```

All the jobs are members of the same serial group, but the distro stage does not run if the pipeline was triggered by a change to the lib.  Only with a change to the app will the distro step run.

In order to get the distro to build when a commit is made to the lib, another resource-dependency must be added to the plan for the distro:

```
  - get: lib
    passed: [build-lib]
    trigger: true
```

In this simplified setup, this is not such a bad deal, but our real situation has more than ten libs and five apps with various dependencies on the libs.  These apps should then be packaged together.  If the distro must depend on all the libs in addition to the apps, in order to be built for all changes, the setup becomes very complicated, both in the YAML-files and the graphical view of the pipeline.  We also want to add a fourth stage to do UI-testing of the completed distro, but that is almost unmanageable with all the required dependencies.

Is there some kind of dependency I can set up from distro to app, in order for the distro to build every time the app is built, without the dependency on the lib?

Comment: Does `build-app` grab the lib as well? Like `get: lib; passed: [build-lib]` ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  The 3 lines in the 2nd code-block above is in `build-app`, and I do not see why I have to repeat it in `build-distro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I finally found out what is going on here.  It is actually quite logical:

The dependency triggers are depending on the resource, not the conclusion of a build.  So, if the `build-app` job is run, because it depends on the `lib` resource, this does not change the `app` resource, which the `build-distro` depends on (with the restriction that `build-app` passed).

In order to make this work, there must be output resources from `build-app` that are `put` to a resource that the next stage can discover a change to and trigger on.  We didn't do this, because our builds are done with gradle, and the build-scripts already had functionality to upload the output resources to our local repository where it could be easily downloaded in the next stage.

Comment: A solution to this is to create an s3 resource and 'put' a file there with a timestamp in the filename. Then you can use this file as a method of triggering subsequent jobs, even if there is no change to your code etc. You can also make empty commits to your codebase but that can clog up the git history.